# Detailed Monitoring of a NetGear GS748Tv3

Tags: netgear

I am having an issue where, at seemingly random times, a large portion of my RDP Terminal Server users are being disconnected for no apparent reason.  The disconnection is very short lived, and often the RDP client will reconnect automatically, but many of our HP thin clients do not.

I suspect the switch that we have in our data rack, a Netgear GS748T, which is currently serving triple duty, with a portion VLANed for SAN traffic to our Netapp filer, a portion VLANed for vMotion traffic and the rest VLANed for connections to the rest of our standard network from the three vmWare hosts, and CIFS access to the Netapp.

Does anyone know of any non-standard activity logging capability for the GS748T?  There is very little in the web interface, and less online.

I believe that this must be caused by some kind of port reset on the ports that feed back to the rest of the network, but without any kind of log, that is difficult to check.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: Have you updated the firmware on the switch? It does seem like the different revisions fix a TON of issues. Past that, it may support syslogging.

Comment: The use of a low-end "smart switch" without meaningful diagnostics as a core component of your infrastructure seems disproportional to the rest of your rather highly-priced infrastructure. Why don't you simply use a "proper" managed switch? It would make troubleshooting much easier

Comment: Great point dj.  All of the rest of my Adtran switching infrastructure supports what I need, and yet this switch, the center of all dataflow, is not of the same caliber.  I believe I have an underutilized Adtran NetVanta 1524ST that I can swap over to.  My wife is going to be thrilled; another night here...

Comment: @Spaceman: I have the latest firmware staged, but have not found a time to be able to apply it.  More night visits I guess.

Comment: Glenn, tell your wife that the new Coach purse she's been dreaming about makes all of your late nights at work worth it. ;)

Comment: I've just moved the LAN vLan from the Netgear switch to a fully managed Adtran switch.  I know I can log errors on this switch.  Thanks for the suggestion syneticon-dj.  Can't believe I didn't consider that option... rookie mistake (and I shouldn't make those...)

Comment: syneticon-dj, if you want to change your comment to an answer I will accept it... since moving the LAN vLan from the NetGear to the AdTran we have had NO issues at all like what I asked about.  Thanks for the "D'oh" slap.